# select other values rather than group by django

Tags: django

Lets take an example

```
OrderItem.objects.filter(order=order).values('item')\
  .annotate(number_sold= Count('item'), Amount= Sum('total'))

This query return me 3 columns which are item, number_sold, Amount....
If add other columns in values it will also be added in Group by clause.
```

Is there a way that i can select other column and cannot appear in group by clause

Answer (score 0):

No. At the SQL level, if it's not in the group by clause it will need an aggregation performed on it. Since you're not specifying an aggregation to occur on it, it needs to go in the group by clause if it's supposed to be returned.

Edit:

If you consider the following table as a table in your database:

```
ColA | ColB | ColC
 1   |  A   | True
 1   |  A   | False
 1   |  B   | True
 1   |  B   | False
 2   |  A   | True
 2   |  A   | False
 2   |  B   | True
 2   |  B   | False
```

If you want the max value for ColA you could run `select max(ColA) from table;`. This would return 2.

However, if you specify that you want the column ColB to be returned, the system needs to know how to handle them. Otherwise it doesn't know which ones to show, since obviously there are 4 rows that have the value 2 for ColA, but they have 2 different values for ColB.

So that's where the group by comes into play. If you do

```
select max(ColA), ColB from table group by ColB;
```

It will return:

```
Max | ColB
  2 | A
  2 | B
```

Comment: Done, but you can read better and more detailed information about SQL aggregation here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-agg.html

Comment: No, it's a constraint at the SQL level. It's not a problem with your models or the filter you're doing.